# Creating Constructors in

Tags: solidity, remix

How do I create a constructor in solidity?

My goal is to have values initialized when the smart contract is deployed. As a java programmer, I default to a constructor to handle this.

```
contract NimGamev3 {

...

constructor(NimGamev3) internal {

...

}

...

}
```

I've read that you should use the constructor keyword to create a constructor to initialize values. This doesn't raise any errors when using remix. When I copy the code to Ethereum Wallet I get an error, "Could not compile source code. Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidty' constructor(NimGamev3) internal {"

When I use a function to initialize variables, it is not called on when the contract is deployed, and if I make it public, it can be initialized multiple times which is not the intended function of the constructor.

Note: I am currently using 0.4.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the name `constructor` for the constructor is in the version `0.4.22` of Solidity. You are using `0.4.21`, which doesn't implement it.

Comment: Changing my version of solidity in ethereum wallet does not fix the compile error. Same error message as well. (I changed it to "pragma solidity ^0.4.22" and to "...^0.4.23")

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I reloaded the deploy contract page, and it might have just worked. Let me test this for a few more minutes and I will give you and updates. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! This worked, the issue was ethereum wallet was not recompiling it after I changed the version of solidity. Thank you!